# Java Base64 encoding not working on all platforms

Tags: java, base64, decode

String decodedString = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedPasswordToken.getBytes("UTF-8")));

I am trying to decode a Base64 encoded string using above piece of code. The string which I get after decoding is correct on Windows platform and its different on other (Linux/MAC) platforms.

Can you please help me how to decode it such that it works in both platforms?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a real [mcve]. I would be rather surprised if such simple, common code would really deliver the different results as you are claiming.

Comment: I second @GhostCat. Nevertheless, are you *encoding* using UTF-8 parameter aswell?

Comment: You most likely have a character encoding problem in some other code, that you didn't show us. Probably something that depends on the default char encoding of the system, which is different on different operating systems.